# Trying to deploy a pyautogui crawler on AWS Ec2

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver, web-crawler

I'm new at AWS and I'm trying to deploy a pyautogui crawler on an ubuntu 18.04 ec2 instance.

But when I try to install google chrome I get severel errors.

I used this tutorial to install all the packages https://understandingdata.com/install-google-chrome-selenium-ec2-aws/ buit still got errors.

When running this code below got this error.

```
google-chrome – version && which google-chrome
cat: relocation error: /opt/google/chrome/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
cat: relocation error: /opt/google/chrome/lib/libc.so.6: symbol _dl_starting_up version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in file ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 with link time reference
```

And I don't know how to "open" this chrome tab on a interfaceless server.

Appreciate any help. And if need more info let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions you follow are for **Amazon Linux, not Ubuntu**. Below are steps that should work for Ubuntu (you may need to start with a new instance):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unzip libnss3

cd /tmp/
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/80.0.3987.106/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
chromedriver -version


wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

then

```
google-chrome -version && which google-chrome
```

gives:

```
Google Chrome 85.0.4183.83 
/usr/bin/google-chrome
```

Comment: @AlexandreGentil Can Please try on the new instance, unmodified instance. Your procedure for Amazon Linux broke linkers on the original instance.

Comment: Ok, now the tutorial works. But I can't open the browser. Do u know how to do it?

Comment: Thanks for the help. Do u know where I can find a tutorial to do that? I want to automate a crawler with pyautogui, só I need to open a web browser.

Comment: @AlexandreGentil [here](https://comtechies.com/how-to-set-up-gui-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu-server.html) is one, but I haven't used it. Not sure if it is correct or not.